# Remote connections to Infinispan server - and work with JGroups

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

My setup is an infinispan 8.1.2 server running on AWS using a distributed cache.  For local development, I would like to be able to connect to the instance on AWS, but the server will only start using either 0.0.0.0 or the AWS private IP address. Since JGroups does not work with the 0.0.0.0 address it seems my only option would be to use the AWS private IP.  But this address is not accessible remotely!

Has anyone else run infinispan server and tried to connect from a different subnet?

Comment: I can't recall such problems in AWS, though I was running only embedded mode. Why can't the server start with public IP?

Comment: the aws instance does not appear to be aware of its own public IP (by default).  when I do an "ip addr show" only the AWS internal IP is listed under eth0

Comment: Then use `DescribeInstances` with `network-interface.addresses.association.public-ip`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps but anyway...
You do have a public IP address on AWS, which you can query with some HTTP command (check the docs).

Now, if you can add a NATting rule which forwards traffic between the private and public address, you could use `external_addr` and `external_port` in `TCP` to bind to the *private* address, but send traffic to the *public* address.

This would allow you to access a JGroups node from another subnet, or even the internet. You probably have to modify your security policy and expose the externally accessible ports. YMMV

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer this, Bela.  Wildfly/Infinispan wouldn't start when passed the public IP, but perhaps I can configure it so that it can recognize the address.